# Crawl Wikipedia pages starting from a seed

Tags: web-crawler, wikipedia

Which is the most efficient way of crawling Wikipedia starting from a seed?

What I would like to do is to start from a seed (i.e., a specific page) and then crawl the pages that are at a maximum distance of `N` from the seed. The crawling should be done by navigating the links that are contained in the page.

For instance, in the case `N=2`, I would expand to each page that is linked in the seed (`distance=1`) and then, for each one of these pages, expand again to the pages it links (`distance=2`).

A Java solution would be preferred, but a script (e.g., Python) is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API to do this, specifically [the `links` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#links_.2F_pl).

The initial query would look like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Page

[There are libraries for accessing the API from almost any language.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code)